# Programming a boolean program using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this homework to do and I dont really understand why my program doesnt really work(prints 1 constantly).

I am supposed create a program that receives a number and a digit from the user(we can assume that the input is ok)
and it prints 1 in case the digit appears inside the number even times. In case it appears odd amount of times it will print 0.
I have to use a boolean recursion function.

can someone please tell me whats wrong with it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isEven(int num, int dig);
void main()
{
    bool res;
    int num, dig;
    cout << "Please enter a number and a digit" << endl;
    cin >> num >> dig;
    cout << isEven(num, dig);
}
bool isEven(int num, int dig)
{
    bool res;
    int counter = 0;
    if (num < 10)
    {
        if (counter % 2 != 0)
            res=false;
        else
            res=true;
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        res=isEven(num / 10, dig);
        if (num % 10 == dig)
            counter++;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Learn to use a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It'll show you what's wrong with this program in a few minutes, and will save you hours in the future.

Comment: Note that `void main` is invalid C++. Use `int main` instead.

Comment: BTW, when playing with digits, prefer to keep the number as a string.  Each digit can be converted from character to number by subtracting `'0'`:  `int digit = number_as_text[i] - '0';`

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the value of your `counter` down through your recursive calls - it's effectively unused in your current implementation.

You're also missing one check if `dig % 10 == num` - in your code, you never check the last digit of the number.

```
bool isEven(int num, int dig, int counter)
{
    bool res;

    if (num % 10 == dig)
        counter++;

    if (num < 10)
    {
        if (counter % 2 != 0)
            res=false;
        else
            res=true;
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        res=isEven(num / 10, dig, counter);
        return res;
    }
}
```

And you can just call it with `isEven(num, dig, 0)` or create a wrapper function that takes just `num` and `dig` and calls this version with `0`.

---

Note that there's a (imo) more elegant recursive expression of this function without using counters, although it's got some slightly unintuitive bits to it:

```
bool isEven(int num, int dig)
{
    // Base case, single digit
    // If num % 10 == dig on this last digit, we've got 1 match (odd, so return false)
    if (num < 10)
        return num % 10 != dig;

    bool result = isEven(num / 10, dig);
    if (num % 10 == dig) // This digit matches, count one more/flip the result
        result = !result;

    return result;
}
```